# React native swipe out to delete conflict with navigation back

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
Code:

 npm install --save react-native-swipeout

 var swipeoutBtns = [
 {
   text: 'Button'
 }
```

]

```
swipetoDelete()
{
 alert('delete')
},
<Swipeout onPress={()=>this.swipetoDelete()}  right={swipeoutBtns}>
  <View  key={i} style={styles.containerSectionMenuOption}>
   <TouchableOpacity>
  ..
  ..
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Swipeout>
```

I am working tab bar based project.I am trying for swipe to delete function.while swipe in it is working fine.when i swipe out it is moving to previous screen and also onPress event does not fire.How to solve this issue?any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `react-native-router-flux`, at your Routes page, where you declare all scenes, you can set that spectacular scene to be opened Vertically, so swiping horizontally won't go back. or you can simply disable the swipe to go back by setting panhandlers for that scene to null.

```
<Scene key="login" direction="vertical">
```